# Javascript didn't read all var

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Exchange rate</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="exstyle.css"/>

 </head>

 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     d=35;

     e=40;

     x=prompt("Insert Value");
     var z=x/d,
        g=x/e;


    var currency;
     currency=prompt("Insert Country");

     if(currency="dollar"){
        document.write(+z);
     }
     else 
         if(currency="euro"){
         document.write(+g);
    }


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I try to run this code, the result always the same.
Example I input 4000 as a value of x and when I insert currency as dollar I got 114.28 which is correct but when I insert currency as euro the result still the same as dollar. did I do something wrong?

Comment: `=` is assignment operator. `==`  or `===` are comparison operator

Comment: There is a difference between `=` and `==`. When you do  = , you are assigning instead of comparing. Correct in other places too.

When you write `if(currency="dollar")`, it silently assigns the value and goes inside.

Comment: use === instead of ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the comparison operator (==)

```
  if(currency=="dollar"){
    document.write(+z);
 }
 else 
     if(currency=="euro"){
     document.write(+g);
}
```